Is there a way to delete specific items from Volume Grid?
I used an extension called VDB to transfer the smoke simulation created in Blender to a program called VRED.
This can be checked with OpenVDB in Blender, but the problem is that VRED can only accommodate a maximum of 4 Volume Grids.
So I want to delete unnecessary items in the Grid in Blender.

Those look like the results of sub-simulations in Smoke & Fire. Not sure how to delete them now, but having them turned off to start with when simulating might be a way to not add them.

You are saying to disable that item before exporting the simulation to VDB. So, for example, is there a way for me to disable Color in the Inflow property?

No, you cannot turn off Smoke Color for simulation, @TheLabCat is wrong there. You could stop the generation of smoke completely, but I guess you want smoke.

So there is no way to delete the desired item from that list?

No, the simulation stores those attributes and they are there. Just like if a mesh has vertices, they have position data. You cannot have the vertices without position, even if they were all 0. The simulation might not use some of those attributes or their data might be empty or 0, but the attributes are there. I don't know if there is some kind of VDB editor software somewhere where you can remove certain attributes from the files...

I understood...then I need VDB editor or something...
Thanks for comment! :D
